# Как дать возможность редактировать и просматривать только страницы для роли в Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с ситуацией.

Хочу сделать на своем сайте wordpress определенную роль, при которой пользователь сможет редактировать только одну страницу, которую я позволю. В интернете есть инструкции и справка на самом сайте wordpress, так что проблем с созданием роли не возникло. Я просто выдал права для редактирования  только своих записей. Вот тут начинается самое интересное: в админ панели этой роли все равно доступно создание своих постов, видны все записи, если нет своих, а также просмотр всех комментариев сайта, что конечно же мне не нужно. Такое возникает так как без прав на создание записей войти в админ панель нельзя. Существует плагин, который скрывает для определенной роли пункты в меню, да, он работает, да, если знаешь ссылку все равно можно увидеть контент. От сюда вопрос: 
Как более красиво можно организовать Возможность выдачи права для пользователя  редактировать свою страницу и просматривать комментарии только к ней.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**add_role():** - добавить пользовательскую роль.

**remove_role():** - удалить пользовательскую роль.

**get_role():** - получает информацию о роли и ее возможностях.

```
function add_roles_on_init() {
      $role_created= add_role(
      'my_custom_role', __( 'My Custom Role' ),
       array(
       'read' => true,
       'edit_posts' => true,
       'create_posts' => true,
       'edit_others_posts' => false,
       'delete_posts' => false,
       'activate_plugins' => true,
       'delete_plugins' => true,
       'edit_plugins' => true,
       'install_plugins' => true,
       'update_plugins' => true,
       ));
  if ( null !== $role_created ) {
       echo 'Contribute and Manage Plugins Role Created!';
  }else {
      echo 'You already have this role!';
  }
}
add_action('init', 'add_roles_on_init');
```

Вывод только своих записей в админки.

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'post_author' ); 
function post_author() {
  global $post;

 if(current_user_can('my_custom_role') ) {    

   global $query_string;

   query_posts($query_string . "&author=".get_current_user_id());

 } 
}
```

Comment: Второй участок кода помог. Можно сделать, чтобы комментарии в админке показывались только на свои записи?

Comment: @Dvashington момент

Comment: Кстати, что я заметил. когда добавлял роль с помощью функции, как в первый, так и во второй раз (вашим способом), пользователь с этой ролью не показывался в списке при редактировании страницы, нельзя было поменять автора. Пришлось редактировать уже имеющуюся роль и снимать с нее права.

Comment: @Dvashington с комментариями как то сложнее.

Comment: Так или иначе вы уже помогли)

Comment: C комментариями я почти разобрался сам

Comment: @Dvashington это радует )